# Unable to clone function into child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```
<Modal>
    <InviteForm {...props} />
</Modal>
```

in Modal

```
render() {
    return (<div>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {hideModal: this.hideModal})}
    </div>)
}
```

In the InviteForm though, the hideModal function does not appear in the props. Am I cloning the element improperly?

Answer (score 0):

React children are confusing because it can be a single object or an array of children.

I would use `React.Children.map`

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child){
  return React.cloneElement(child, {hideModal: this.hideModal})
}.bind(this))
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children